# Time complexity of finding predecessor for a dictionary implemented as a sorted array

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

I'm currently reading "The Algorithm Design Manual" by Steven Skiena. On page 73, he discusses the time complexity of implementing $ Predecessor(D, k) $ and $ Successor(D, k) $ and suggests that it takes O(1) time.

If the data structure looks something like

```
[(k0, x), (k1, x), ...]
```

where the keys `k0` to `kn` are sorted, given `k`, I thought the `successor(D, k)` would first have to search the sorted array for `k` ( $ O(log n) $ ) and then get the successor ( $ O(1) $ ) since the array is sorted, and hence the overall time complexity should be $ O(log n) $ instead of $ O(1) $ as mentioned in the book. This should also apply for `predecessor(D, k)`.

For an unsorted array, the time complexity for predecessor and successor remain as $ O(n) $ since searching the unsorted array also takes $ O(n) $.

Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that on page 73, the author defines the abstract functions $Predecessor(D, k)$ and $Successor(D, k)$, which find the predecessor and successor of a given *key*.

But the chart on page 74 lists the interfaces as $Predecessor(L, x)$ and $Successor(L, x)$, which find the predecessor and successor of a given *entry index*. Clearly this is O(1) for a sorted random access datastructure.

This particular interface is, in general, more useful and more efficient than the key-based interface previously presented, since it more accurately represents the cost of iterating through the dictionaries elements. Most such interfaces do, in fact, take some kind of cursor ("iterator" in C++ parlance) as an argument and return another cursor as a result.

Comment: Isn't $ x $ in this case the value in the (key, value) pair?

Comment: @ackerleytng, no. It's the index of the pair in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Usually dictionaries are not sorted. There are no provisions for accessing items in sorted order, and finding the predecessor and successor *of a key* take O (n) and are not really useful.

What you *do* however is iterating through a dictionary, that is you have a loop that will visit each key, or each value, or each key-value pair in the dictionary exactly once. Such an iterator would keep track of a position of an item in the dictionary and would have to be able to find the previous or next position in a way that allows visiting each item exactly once, and that is preferably fast.

If you implement a dictionary as a sorted array, going to the previous or next position is trivially O(1), and it just happens to return the items in sorted order. A dictionary implemented as an unsorted array, with n/2 instead of log n access on average to find an existing item, can also trivially iterate in O(1) (and for small n it will be faster because n/2 is still not large compared to log n, and the code is faster).

If you implement a dictionary using a sorted tree, or a hash table, then iterating may be more difficult; but a sorted tree could be stored in an array, and a hash table will often use an array that is not very much bigger than n, so you would expect at least amortized O(1) to iterate (or O(n) to iterate through *all* elements).